# PostgreSQL can't aggregate data from many tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

For simplicity, I will write the minimum number of fields in the tables.
Suppose I have this tables: items, item_photos, items_characteristics.

```
create table items (
  id               bigserial primary key,
  title            jsonb                                   not null,
);
create table item_photos (
  id         bigserial primary key,
  path       varchar(1000)                not null,
  item_id    bigint references items (id) not null,
  sort_order smallint                     not null,
  unique (path, item_id)
);
create table items_characteristics (
  item_id                  bigint references items (id),
  characteristic_id        bigint references characteristics (id),
  characteristic_option_id bigint references characteristic_options (id),
  numeric_value            numeric(19, 2),
  primary key (item_id, characteristic_id),
  unique (item_id, characteristic_id, characteristic_option_id));
```

And I want to aggregate all the photos and characteristics of one item.
For a start, I got this.

```
select i.id                                                                              as id,
       i.title                                                                           as title,

       array_agg( ip.path)                                 as photos,

       array_agg(
         array [ico.characteristic_id, ico.characteristic_option_id, ico.numeric_value]) as characteristics_array
FROM items i
       LEFT JOIN item_photos ip on i.id = ip.item_id
       LEFT JOIN items_characteristics ico on ico.item_id = i.id
GROUP BY i.id
```

The first problem here arises in the fact that if there are 4 entries in item_characteristics that relate to one item, and, for example, item_photos did not have entries, I get an array of four null elements in the photos field `{null, null, null, null}`.
So I had to use array_remove:

```
array_remove(array_agg(ip.path), null)                                   as photos
```

Further, if I have 1 photo and 4 characteristics, I get a duplicate of 4 photo entries, for example: `{img/test-img-1.png,img/test-img-1.png,img/test-img-1.png,img/test-img-1.png}`

So I had to use distinct:

```
array_remove(array_agg(distinct ip.path), null)                                   as photos,

array_agg(distinct
         array [ico.characteristic_id, ico.characteristic_option_id, ico.numeric_value]) as characteristics_array
```

The decision is rather awkward as for me. 
The situation is complicated by the fact that I had to add 2 more fields to item_characteristics:

```
string_value jsonb, --string value
json_value jsonb --custom value
```

And so I need to aggregate already 5 values ​​from item_characteristics, where 2 are already jsonb and distinct can have a very negative impact on performance.
Is there any more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate *before* joining:

```
SELECT i.id as id, i.title as title, ip.paths, null as photos,
       ico.characteristics_array
FROM items i LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ip.item_id, array_agg( ip.path) as paths
      FROM item_photos ip
      GROUP BY ip.item_ID
     ) ip 
     ON ip.id = i.item_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ico.item_id,
             array_agg(array [ico.characteristic_id, ico.characteristic_option_id, ico.numeric_value]
                       ) as characteristics_array
      FROM items_characteristics ico
      GROUP BY ico.item_id
     ) ico
     ON ico.item_id = i.id
```

Comment: Thanks, at once I could not guess about it.